# Unable to get my first Remote Event Receiver working inside Office 365, as it is not being fired

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, remote-event-receiver

I want to develop my first sharepoint add-in for implementing a remote event receiver. so i did these steps, without any success in forcing the RER to fire:-

1. I have office 365 + Visual Studio 2015 professional.
2. I open VS 2015 -> create a new project of type SharePoint Add-in:-
   [image]
3. then i enter the following:-

   - Team site collection url
   - add-in type as SharePoint-hosted

[image]
4. after that i mention that the type is for office 365:-
[image]
5. i right click on the project>> new item >> RER + to fire on custom lists when items are being added:
[image]
[image]
6. then i added this test code inside the remote event receiver, to update a custom list items' title to be "updated title":-

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

            using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdding)
                    {
                        result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("Title", "updated title");

                    }
                  //  clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                  //  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

7. then i try running the project but i got this error:-

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install SharePoint Add-in':
>   Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site.

so i realize that i can not directly add my add-in to a team site.
8. so i changed the add-in url to use the developer site url.
9. then i run the add-in, and i got this page, which seems inside my dev site collection:-
[image]

10. so i trusted the app, then i add a new custom list, **but when i add a new item inside the new custom list, title did not get modified, so seems the RER did not get fired**.

so are my above steps valid? or there is something missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RERs can only be Provider Hosted. You've set up your Addin as SharePoint Hosted.

[Use remote event receivers in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint)

> SharePoint-hosted add-ins do not support remote event receivers. To use remote event receivers, you need to use a provider-hosted add-in. You should not use remote event receivers for synchronization scenarios, or for long running processes. For more information, see How to: Create an add-in event receiver.

Comment: but all over the web and YouTube you can find RER being added at first as sharepoint-hosted add-in , then when you add a RER item inside the sharepoint hosted add-in a new web project of type provider-hosted will be created.. and almost every tutorial i viewed ,start by creating sharepoint-hosted app and not provider-hosted...

Comment: I'd suggest you read the documentation, it's clear that RERs are only supported in Provider Hosted addins. Yes, there is a SharePoint component ("addin"), but that's just for authorization/trust purposes.

Comment: @Trvor ok now i created a new provider hosted app, then i added a new RER, after that i run the application which get hosted inside this url `https://localhost:44313/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=https://a*****.sharepoint.com/sites/dev&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=16.0.7213.1208&SPAppWebUrl=https://*****SP-2c49524ea3c40a.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SharePointAddIn19` but when i added a new item inside my custom list its title did not change... so seems the RER is not working